# What is the best way to implement a cross-platform, multi-threaded server in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, network-programming, client-server

Part of the development team I work with has been given the challenge of writing a server for integration with our product. We have some low-level sensor devices that provide a C SDK, and we want to share them over a network for use by people collecting data. Sounds simple, right? Someone would connect a sensor device to their machine in one part of the building and run our server, thus sharing the device(s) with the rest of the network. Then a client would connect to that server via our application and collect sensor readings from the device.

I created a simple, language-agnostic network protocol, and a reference implementation in Java. The problem is creating an implementation that will work with our devices that only provide an SDK written in C. We were thinking of doing the following:

1. Create polling threads that collect and store the most recent readings from each connected device.
2. Use a multi-threaded server to spin off each incoming connection to a worker thread.
3. When a worker thread receives a request for a sensor reading, the most recent value collected by the polling thread is sent back to the client.

That's a lot of threading, especially in C. So, to review, the general requirements are:

- Runs on Windows XP/Vista, Linux, and OS X machines
- Written in C or C++, to interact with the C SDK we have
- Accepts a variable number of simultaneous connections (worker threads)
- Must use threads, not forking (don't want to deal with another layer of IPC)

Can anyone suggest a library and preferably some example code to get use started?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've used [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread.html) & [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) to build a multi-threaded server on Windows & Linux systems. The tutorials made it easy to get started.

Comment: This combination appears to be exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: I would strongly recommend you don't write a server, and consider refactoring it out of your design. See my answer for more detail.

Comment: I agree with frankodwyer, no need for a server for this application... but if you insist on writing a server for this, you use a single-thread and multiplex the network I/O, make sure to async I/O as well (Boost.Asio should be good for this).

Answer (score 9):

The best way to write such a server is not to write one, and to rearchitect your system so it is not necessary, and/or to reuse components that already exist. Because:

> Someone would connect a sensor device
>   to their machine in one part of the
>   building and run our server, thus
>   sharing the device(s) with the rest of
>   the network.

This also has the potential to share the entire machine with rest of the network, if your code has a vulnerability (which it probably will, as you're writing it in C++ from scratch and inventing a new protocol).

So, do it the other way around. Install a simple client on the machine that has the sensor hardware, then run it either all the time, or periodically, and have it push (post) results to a central server. The central server could even be a standard web server. Or it could be a database. (Notice that both of these have been written already - no need to reinvent the wheel ;-)

Your application then works the same way you have in mind now, however it collects data from the database rather than the sensors.  The part running on the machine with the sensor, however, has shrunk from a multi-threaded custom server nightmare, to a nice little single threaded command line client that only makes *outgoing* connections, and which can be run from cron (or equivalent on windows).

Even if you need real time data collection (and from your description it sounds like you do not) it still may be better for the sensor collector be a client and not a server. Let it open a long lived connection to a central collector (or a group of them) and await instructions to provide its data.

edit: ceretullis and pukku's answers suggest a nice variation on this using multicast - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383371/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-cross-platform-multi-threaded-server-in-cc#383502) and the comments

Comment: One more benefit in the separate server solution (centralized or distributed) becomes clear when you need to add *another* sensor, which all the clients need to see as well... Implementing that may be tedious given the server-per-sensor approach, but should be a breeze in frankodwyer's setting.

Answer (score 7):

[Douglas Schmidt's ACE (Adaptive Communications Environment)](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) is a [mature,](http://freshmeat.net/projects/ace/) [highly portable](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.FAQ.html#Q0b) open-source framework for building high-performance multithreaded servers.  It's mainly aimed at telecommunication applications, but has been used for a [variety of projects](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-users.html).  It also comes with an [object request broker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_request_broker) called [TAO](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/TAO.html) (if you're into [CORBA](http://www.omg.org/gettingstarted/corbafaq.htm))

One claim to fame of the framework is that it supports many threading models (thread pool, thread per request, asynchronous + threads etc.), so you can use its thread management in a way that's optimal for your application.   This is actually the most interesting feature  of the system - the server framework functionality comes out of the box. Most of the other libraries I've seen suggested here would still require you to implement much of this functionality yourself.

There is quite a bit of [electronic documentation](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-papers.html) and also [several books](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE/) written about it.  It's not the most warm and fluffy of systems and is really built for speed rather than comfort - but we are using C++.  You will probably find that it's much less effort to get your head around ACE than try to rebuild the functionality and debug all the synchronisation.

Oh, and by the way, it's [free](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-copying.html) as in speech - and as in beer.  If you want to a commercial route there is also an [ecosystem of consultants](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/commercial-support.html) that will provide support and mentoring services for it.  A tutorial with some code snippets can be found [here.](http://www.huihoo.org/ace_tao/ACE-5.2+TAO-1.2/ACE_wrappers/docs/tutorials/001/page02.html)

Answer (score 4):

I would use QT.  It has a cross-platform threading support.  Good documentation:

[QT Threading Documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/threads.html)

Their signal/slot messaging mechanism works seamlessly between threads too.

Comment: Cool -- I never realized QT had an easy to use cross-platform threading component to it.

Comment: Qt isn't free though, and for small projects the price can be rather alot.

Comment: It is now, for most definitions of free (http://www.qtsoftware.com/about/news/lgpl-license-option-added-to-qt)

Answer (score 4):

Not really an answer to your question, but since it sounds like you are actually more familiar with Java than C/C++, why not continue with your reference implementation, and connect to the SDK using [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). (I never really used it, but I figured it would be useful exactly for these kinds of situations.)

Alternatively, you could easily write a simple C program that employs the SDK, and then sends the data to your Java program, using socket-based streams for example. This way, you could again handle the more difficult stuff in Java.

Comment: We actually considered this, but we decided finding a cross-platform threading library would be easier and less troublesome than trying to learn JNI -- no one in the team is really familiar with it. Since JNI is one of those easy-to-screw-up things, threads seemed that safer option :-)

Comment: JNI is a bit tricky to get started with, but we're talking about two days to get it working. It would have been my suggestion as well considering that the target hardware is powerfull and that code in java already exists.

Answer (score 3):

I'd also like to recommend [The Spread Toolkit](http://www.spread.org/), which (according to the project's web site) is "an open source toolkit that provides a high performance messaging service that is resilient to faults across local and wide area networks". I have used it couple of times in situations which sound very similar to yours. Essentially, it gives you the server that [frankodwyer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383371/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-cross-platform-multi-threaded-server-in-cc#383436).

The Spread daemon (i.e., the server) ain't multithreaded, but it's really fast and scales well up to at least hundreds or thousands of clients. Moreover, the protocol caters for reliable IP multicasting, which (in a multi-client environment) may give you (performance-wise) a definite edge against anything implemented using point-to-point TCP or UDP connections only. (But: do not try to implement reliable IP multicasting yourself... apparently, the Spread project has produced a number of PhD/MSc theses as a side-product - or is it the toolkit that is the side-product while the main emphasis was always academic research? I don't really know...).

Since Spread has C and Java client APIs (plus Python), it sounds like a very good match to your problem. They have two licensing models; the first alternative is close to BSD's. And it's cross-platform of course (regarding both the client, and the server).

However, Spread will (of course) not do everything for you. Most prominently perhaps, it does not do persistence (i.e., if your client is offline or otherwise unable to receive messages, Spread will not buffer them, beyond a very small number of msgs at least). But fortunately it's not really too difficult to roll your own persistence implementation on top of what Spread does guarantee (well I don't even know if such an issue is important for you, or not). Second, Spread limits your messages to 100 kilobytes each, but that limit is also quite easy to circumvent simply by making the sender chop a big message into a number of smaller ones and then concatenating 'em at the receiver.

Answer (score 2):

I use [libevent](http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/)  to multiplex network I/O. You should consider it as an alternative to Boost.Asio.

The libevent API provides a mechanism to execute a callback function when a specific event occurs on a file descriptor or after a timeout has been reached. Currently, libevent supports /dev/poll, kqueue, event ports, select, poll and epoll.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with frankodwyer, flip the protocol from a pull model to a push model.

Have the computer with the connected sensor broadcast the readings over UDP multicast at 100Hz (or whatever makes since for your sensors) whenever the sharing service is running. Then write clients that read the multicast data.

Alternatively you could use broadcast UDP instead of multicast.

BTW, this is how many GPS, Lidar, and other sensors do things.

Comment: nice use of multicast, but they risk losing readings with UDP (no guaranteed delivery - the network is free to drop UDP packets on the floor). I don't know if anyone has come up with a 'multicast TCP' as yet - though I do know that people have worked on that problem, it is not easy.

Comment: @frankodwyer: yes they have, see my reply :) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383371/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-cross-platform-multi-threaded-server-in-cc#383519) ... of course the guarantees are not really equal to TCP's, but then again it's a different problem.

Comment: thanks, i didn't know about spread, it sounds really interesting. reliable multicast could be an elegant solution. Cisco also have something called PGM that does reliable multicast - it works best if you have Cisco kit though.

Comment: Do you know the likelihood of a UDP packet getting dropped on a LAN? Unless you have your switches running at 95% utilization or higher UDP is probably safe.

Comment: @ceretullis - that's probably correct (I haven't tested it myself). However I know that with syslog-udp people have tested it under heavy load and found almost 50% of messages go missing even on a local domain socket! Also UDP can be dropped anywhere including from a host stack, even the transmit q!

Comment: @frankodwyer, I think everyone knows there is potential for UDP to be dropped. I think also think everyone widely overestimates the importance of their data when deciding against UDP. For sensors, you could have the clients implement a Kalman filter to deal with a dropped reading or two.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Cross-Platform API or Create your own API which you change on each Architecture.

Also revise this: http://www.goingware.com/tips/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use C (and not C++), the [NSPR library](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/nspr/) might provide what you need...

Answer (score -2):

I highly recommend you consider the prototype design pattern.

I used this pattern to write a protocol agnostic server in C++ that I have used for everything from HTTP Web Services to custom proprietary binary protocols.

Basically, the idea is this:

The Server takes care of accept()ing incoming connections on a particular port and creating threads (or processes) to handle those connections.

When you're trying to build a generic server you realize that you cannot really read or write any data without making assumptions about the protocol... So, the trick is to use the prototype pattern.

Create a "ConnectionHandlerBase" class with a pure "HandleConnection() = 0" method. Make the users of the server class subclass this class with their own implementation. Additionally, this class implements a "Clone()" method that returns a copy of itself... This way the server can create new instances of it without needing to know its type... Then when you get a connection, call "Clone()" on your prototypical instance and have the handling thread call "HandleConnection()" on this object.

At application startup, the user of the server class has to call something like this:

"Server.AttachConnectionPrototype( &MyConnectionObject );"